# Exit loop when 'Q' is entered

Tags: c, while-loop, getchar

I want to have a program in c where user is asked for input at the beginning of the loop and end the while loop if the user hits Q.
I am in search of efficient code and without fflush() call as well.[I consider user can input 'a', 'abc', 'ab2c' etc at the input].
I tried in following manner but if i press 'a' it also includes '\0' which causes additional call for loop. Similarly if user enters 'abc' or 'ab2c' etc. loop is executed multiple times.

```
int main (void)
{
    char exit_char = '\0';
    puts ("Entering main()");

    while (1)
    {
        printf ("Please enter your choice: ");

        exit_char = getchar();
        if (exit_char == 'Q')
            break;

        f1();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

please suggest a appropriate solution.

Comment: do you just want to loop over getchar until that is 'q'?

Comment: I think you misunderstand how `getchar` works, it will not return `'\0'`. However, it does return an ***`int`***, and you need to check for `EOF` as well.

Comment: You understand that the user has to press the `Enter/Return` key to flush the input buffer?

Comment: @rpattiso you are right, I just get mad when I see it because many programmers uset unnecessarily, I am deleting the comment.

Comment: I mentioned wrongly about '\0' in case of getchar. getchar() gets a char along with the newline(user pressed enter) which is part of buffer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In situations like yours, it's best to read the input line by line, and then process each line.

```
#define MAX_LINE_LENGTH 200

char* getInput(char line[], size_t len)
{
   printf ("Please enter your choice: ");
   return fgets(line, len, stdin);
}

int main (void)
{
   char line[MAX_LINE_LENGTH];

   while ( getInput(line, sizeof(line)) )
   {
      if ( toupper(line[0]) == 'Q' )
         break;

      // Process the line

   }    
}
```

Comment: or `if (toupper(line[0]) == 'Q')`.

Comment: Thank you very much. I got the answer.
I assume its possible to reduce the MAX_LINE_LENGTH = 2 or so. Is there any side effect of that?

Comment: Using `MAX_LINE_LENGTH = 2` won't be right. You need one space for the terminating null character, one for the newline character, and anything else that you expect to enter in a line. Using 200 gives you a large enough array for simple things. It doesn't cost too much to use 200 compared to using, let's say, 10.

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you want?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int
main(void)
{
    char buffer[100];

    while (1)
     {
        char *line;

        printf("Please enter your choice: ");
        line = fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin);
        if ((line == NULL) || ((toupper(line[0]) == 'Q') && (line[1] == '\n')))
            break;
        printf("Not done yet!\n");
     }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you.
This is good one but still loop is not exited even when user enters the "Qabc". I suppose just "toupper(line[0]) == 'Q'" is enough.

Comment: Yes it's intended that way, and I don't see way are you after such behavior, but @[RSahu](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30332237/1983495)'s does work that way.

Comment: Thank you and @RSahu for the solution. I suppose user may provide input as [Q]uit. I meant q or quit. that should be logically correct. What do you say?

Comment: @Anand If the user types `query` or any other word starting with `Q|q`! it will exit the loop, is that ok?

Comment: As of now i am not concerned with that. Yes later on i will have to think on that.